# consume spring boot rest services from private network

Tags: spring-boot, rest, tunnel, http-tunneling

I want to consume the spring boot rest services deployed behind a firewall. Need a solution for the above scenario. Thank you.

Comment: What does "private" mean here?  Are they behind a firewall that you aren't granted access to?    It's a poorly posed question.

Comment: Yes behind a firewall.

Comment: If they aren't listening on port 80 then you'll have to arrange with the owner of the firewall to open another port for you.  If you can't do that, then you shouldn't have access.  That's the whole point of the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

To access a Rest API behind a firewall you need to open the default HTTP ports in that firewall(80 for HTTP and 443).

That has nothing to do with the technology that you are using to implement the Rest API.

Please provide more details about your question if this is not enough answer for you...

Comment: Actually, Our project based on Active Directory. We have Client jar deployed at the client end and Server Jar present in our local network. We want to establish communication between the two.

Comment: Client should give you access in order to establish communication as its not possible without that.

Comment: Will it be possible by tunnelling?

Comment: That is still not enough description... if you want to make direct communication between client/server. you can setup a VPN server and joining the VPN network from the client side.